# Expo react native app restarts on modal open

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo SDK 35

App works fine on iOS (and previously worked fine on android). Now, whenever I hit a TouchableOpacity that opens a modal (react-native-modal) the app restarts. The TouchableOpacity does wrap an animated View. Sentry doesn't catch anything, but device logs have a few errors:

```
W/unknown:ReactNative(11782): Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit(["appStateDidChange",{"app_state":"background"}])
E/unknown:ReactNative(11782): Tried to remove non-existent frame callback
```

```
E/GraphResponse(11782): {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
```

I'm at a total loss here -- some other modals work totally fine and there are *no* problems on iOS so it doesn't seem like it's an issue with the modal content. And i don't call (or even reference) the graph api anywhere. Has anyone seen this? Sample code below

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => {
     this.toggleView();
     this._openModal({ id: "profile", isOpen: true });
   }}>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>     
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```js
  toggleView = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.mode, {
      toValue: this.mode._value === 0 ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 1000
    }).start();
    this.setState({ profileOpen: !this.state.profileOpen });
  };
```

_openModal isn't the issue here, it's working everywhere else in a pretty large codebase and has been extensively tested.

Comment: having this exact same issue

Comment: check to see if you're in prod mode. that often hides errors in expo.